# How to create tickets in python automatically

Tags: python, algorithm, python-imaging-library

I want to make a program for creating tickets in python. The ticket must consist of a backing, and an overlaid barcode and serial number.
[image]

---

I heard about the PIL library, but as I understand it, it works with ready-made images, i.e. it needs pictures of serial numbers to overlay, but I need to create them automatically. And then generate pdf in this format for printing.
[image]

Which library can be used to do this?

Comment: matplotlib could be useful here. you can also see how barcodes are made in https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/python-barcode

Comment: @jakub Thank you very much, but regarding other tasks, how can I then insert this barcode onto the image, and at least 1000 times, and finally prepare it for printing?

Comment: https://www.ghostscript.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of https://pypi.org/project/python-barcode/ and PIL. Create a ticket class and specify the different elements of the ticket. Copy the generated barcode into an image buffer in on the ticket object, fill out the other info, and add these to a list. Create a class to layout these tickets onto a sheet, and then you can write that sheet out as a PDF. Keep in mind that PIL can only write PDF documents, but cannot open then.

I'd start with getting the templates to generate correctly. Use a different solid fill color for each of the elements (essentially just large colored squares), and then add these to the PDF, adding an option for padding to the layout class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You can clarify two points. 1. Is it possible to make a purely serial number like "AA-00001" in the library that makes barcodes? 2. How is the pdf file generated from several tickets into one?

Comment: You might need to use one of the provided barcode types, check `barcode.PROVIDED_BARCODES` You'll have to create a second image buffer with the correct dimensions and have some sort of layout class take care of placing each of the tickets into that buffer at their correct locations. If you have say 44 tickets, and can only fit 6 tickets to a standard A4 page with your given padding, that class should have a method to iterate over all the tickets, once it reaches max tickets per page, save that one, clear the buffer and start a new one with remaining tickets.